# Find data from the strings of array2 in the array1 and save as new uniq array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to find strings that has data from the strings from the array 2 in the array1 and save result as separate uniq array.

As can you see I search for not exact values. From the `array1` values I know only part of the information, and I want to find the complete strings, with that information, in `array1`. And at the end I want to save what I found. So, I don't have a problem with finding here, but a problem with saving in the valid single JSON.

Array examples:

Array #1:

```
{
    "overflow": [
        "id:address:name:location:email",
        ...
        "id2:address2:name2:location2:email2"
    ]
}
```

Array #2:

```
[
    "location:email",
    ...
    "location2:email2"
]
```

Code:

```
resultArr: function() {
    var arr1 = '/var/log/1.json';
    var arr2 = '/var/log/2.json';
    var arrResult = '/var/log/result.json';
    var arr2Obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(arr2, 'utf-8'));
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2Obj.length; i++) {
        var arr1Obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(arr1, 'utf-8'));
        arr1Obj.overflow = arr1Obj.overflow.filter(function(e) {
            return e.includes(arr2Obj[i])
        });
        fs.appendFile(arrResult, JSON.stringify(arr1Obj, null, 2), 'utf-8');
    }
}
```

My result:

```
[{
    "overflow": [
        "id:address:name:location:email"
    ]
}{
    "overflow": [
        "id54:address54:name54:location54:email56"
    ]
}{
    "overflow": [
        "id2:address2:name2:location2:email2",
        "id6:address6:name6:location2:email2"
    ]
}
```

What I really want:

```
{
    "overflow": [
        "id:address:name:location:email",
        "id54:address54:name54:location54:email56",
        "id6:address6:name6:location2:email2",
        "id2:address2:name2:location2:email2"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading the file again and again, and appending to the result repeatedly, just do both actions only once. All the rest should happen in memory.

You will also get better results (no risk for duplicates in result) when you swap the loops: put the `filter` action as the outer loop. For the inner loop you can use `some`, since one match is enough for the entry to be included:

```
resultArr: function() {
    var arr1 = '/var/log/1.json',
        arr2 = '/var/log/2.json',
        arrResult = '/var/log/result.json',
        arr2Obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(arr2, 'utf-8')),
        arr1Obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(arr1, 'utf-8'));
    arr1Obj.overflow = arr1Obj.overflow.filter(function(e) {
        return arr2Obj.some(function (f) {
            return e.includes(f) 
        });
    });
    fs.writeFileSync(arrResult, JSON.stringify(arr1Obj, null, 2), 'utf-8');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration, you're creating a new object and appening it to a file.

1. JSON is not a good format to append to.
2. You're replacing the array instead of adding fields to it.

You can do it that way, it should work :

```
resultArr: () => {
    let arr1 = '/var/log/1.json';
    let arr2 = '/var/log/2.json';
    let arrResult = '/var/log/result.json';
    let arr2Obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(arr2, 'utf-8'));
    let arr1Obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(arr1, 'utf-8')); // reading only one time   

    arr1Obj.overflow = arr2Obj.map(value => {
        return arr1Obj.overflow.filter(e => return e.includes(value))
    });
    fs.writeFileSync(arrResult, JSON.stringify(arr1Obj, null, 2), 'utf-8'); //Writing only one time
}
```

`Array.map()` executes the closure for each field in your array and group all the values returned by the closure in another array.

I also replaced some keywords to make your code more ES6 compliant. I you really want to append, you should use CSV and not JSON.

Comment: Actually I used apjson module here, but I felt bad about, and result was still not as I wanted.